# Open Printer Dialog for PDF file Automatically

Tags: php, pdf, printing

I know that there are ways to print a PDF to a network printer located on the same network as the server, but that does not help me as the server is remote.  In my situation a user clicks a link to "print labels" which then generates and outputs a PDF file formatted for them.  I currently "stream" the file output to the browser such that Adobe Reader automatically opens it using the following code:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="labels.pdf"');
readfile($ServerPathToFile);
```

Is there something else I can add to this code that will automatically trigger the print dialogue box to open so that they only have to click print?  In this case, Google CloudPrint is not an option, nor are other things that require "special setup" on the user end...as this will be used by a variety of users.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in PHP, since PHP only acts on the server machine.  What you want to do happens on the client machine, so you'd use something like Javascript's `window.print()`.

Comment: @Steve - That won't work because the PDF opens within Adobe Reader (or whatever the user's default PDF software is)...NOT within a web browser window...

Comment: I'm fully aware PDFs don't open in the browser window. The "user's default PDF software" is installed on the user's computer. If you want to print, you have to access the print dialog via the user's computer, which cannot and should not be done using PHP. What if all of the websites you visited could just start running stuff on your machine?

Comment: @Steve - The goal here is simply to have the PDF prompt the user print dialog box.  I am looking for a way when serving the file (which is done via PHP from the SERVER...not client-side) to set some sort of flag to indicate the the software should print.  As others have already suggested, it can be done with JavaScript...but if there is a way to do it in the original file output rather than building extra HTML...that would obviously be a more elegant solution. I am looking for an extra header that i can pass (in PHP) if possible. Please try to keep your postings on-topic and constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could output the PDF to a child window (`<iframe>`) on the same domain and then call `window.print()` on that window.

```
<p>Don't forget to print your document!</p>
<iframe src="/path/to/your/pdfgenerator.php" id="mypdf"></iframe>

<script>
function printIframe(id) {
    var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
    var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
    iframe.focus();
    ifWin.printPage();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

In the iframe page, add this:

```
function printPage() {
    print();
}
```

Comment: @Steve - I rolled back your edit. The `<script>` tag's default type property is "text/javascript"...no need to explicitly set it - it just clutters things. http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Comment: This looks like it would certainly work if it is my best/only option.  I was really hoping that there was an additional flag I could set in PHP in my header when sending the file output that would tell the default application (Adobe Reader in this case) that my intended use is to print.  Maybe there is just no such option...but it sure seems like it would be useful.  If nobody has other ideas along those lines, I will use something like your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no such header to my knowledge.

Comment: @dtbarne "function printPage() {
    print();
}"  - does this go in the pdfgenerator.php page ??? or goes into the page where the iframe resides ??

Comment: where in the iframe page pdfgenerator.php does the function printPage () go ? can you show me ?

Comment: PHP returns an error if you place the print page function inside the pdfgenerator.php...i don't know why this was marked as the answer i can't get it to work, php just spits the error without the error

Comment: @UriahsVictor, sounds like you are confusing client and server-side code. If you're getting an error from PHP, it has nothing to do with the suggestion in this post.

Comment: @dtbarne yh i think i landed the wrong place, was trying to automatically open the print dialog for a page on load. But I figured it out. Just added the JS function for opening the print dialog at the bottom of my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I just got off of a project that printed labels from a browser to a dymo label printer on a network. You must do this with javascript. I used the SDK from Dymo and created my own custom interface to auto print name tags once the person registered at the kiosk. The name badges were then waiting for them at the main checkin station.

The srcipt i used only needed to be installed on the server and all others in the network could print to the network printer.

Comment: sounds interesting...but in this case the "user" will be a variety of people spread across the country, each with different network setups and printers...so PDF printing to whatever locally accessible printers are available is my best option.  That said...i have considered something like what you mentioned for another project i am working on...seems like it could be useful.  I don't suppose you can share your code and post a link here?

Comment: @ROY Finley, would you mind sharing your code? I have a similar project but i want to use a zebra printer and print badges with qr-code on it. I have the user data in a database and i layout a pdf (badge size) with tcpdf_min Thanks in advanced