# PHP output PDF and print page

Tags: php, pdf

I have a script generating PDFs via PHP and I can output the results directly to the browser. Is there a way through PHP and possibly headers to make this output page automatically bring up the print dialog?

Comment: here is quite the same question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736534/open-printer-dialog-for-pdf-file-automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can execute embeded JavaScript in a PHP document that gets executed when the PDF is opened. So, you could embed a `print();` command to open the print dialog as soon as the PDF is opened.

I'm not sure how you're creating the PDF, but you could take a look at the suggestions [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687675/can-a-pdf-files-print-dialog-be-opened-with-javascript) and see if that helps.