# priniting a pdf genrated from php from a iframe using js

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, iframe

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />

    <title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Don't forget to print your document!</p>
<iframe src="genpdf.php" id="pdfDocument"></iframe>

<script>


function printPage() { print(); }

function printIframe(id)
{
    var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
    var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
    iframe.focus();
    ifWin.printPage();
    return false;
}

printIframe('pdfDocument');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

courtesy  [Open Printer Dialog for PDF file Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736534/open-printer-dialog-for-pdf-file-automatically)

However i keep getting this error ...

> TypeError: ifWin.printPage is not a function

not too sure what i am doing wrong and how it can be solved (problem in FF and chrome) ..

thanks in advance.

Comment: it says that "function printPage() { print(); }" should go inot the iframe ...... i tired adding a script tag to the actual php file that doesnt work ...  how do i add script to an iframe ?????

Comment: post the code of iframe

Comment: @Ankit iframe page is a pure php page that generates a pdf ....

Comment: then call the print method of iFrame directly as i stated in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Yes You need to put printPage function inside Iframe but there is **one more way** you can call `print` method of the window object of iframe directly without the need of `printPage()` like

```
ifWin.print();
```

instead of

```
ifWin.printPage();
```